# REST Services consumed, the Domain Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, .net-4.0, domain-driven-design

This question touches on what I am talking about:

[Consuming REST Web Service in .NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970542/consuming-rest-web-service-in-net-mvc-3)

And also this is in the right area:

[Is it good to return domain model from REST api over a DDD application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943758/is-it-good-to-return-domain-model-from-rest-api-over-a-ddd-application)

So...

I have several resources (WCF REST) which spit out XML. From ASP.NET MVC, the approach until now has been to retrieve the resource as XML via the resource URI (http://uri.com/collection), deserialise this to the domain model and then eventually use AutoMapper to map to DTOs. In the ASP.NET MVC controllers, these DTOs are serialised as JSON which is then presented using some fancy JavaScript library in the view.

This felt like a more pure approach, separating the domain model from the view model.

I have been looking at other ASP.NET MVC applications and people are referencing their resource (WCF REST) contracts in the ASP.NET MVC controller, and therefore having a dependency on the assembly that contract lives in. Then they are serialising this as JSON and doing pretty much the same as me to present the data.

Although my way is more pure, I feel that the other method is more pragmatic.

I am confused. Without procrastinating I want to build the best possible solution.

And to confuse me even more, are there other approaches to do what I am doing?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what your question really is. If it has to do with using XML versus JSON, I would say to [use RestSharp to consume your services and be done with it](http://restsharp.org/). Let it do the boilerplate code for you. If you are looking to expose the API differently, then I would suggest something like [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/), which creates an API that can be consumed however you want (XML, JSON, etc). I am not sure if this answers your question...

Comment: My question was more around my approach being to GET the resource and then deserialise this to a domain model, map to DTO and then seriliase to JSON versus the other approach of referencing the resource's contract and serialising the resource's DTOs as JSON.

Comment: I like the look of RestSharp, so far I have been using the MicroSoft HttpClient.

Comment: @youwhut I am not sure where to start...but I think you need to read up more on REST...it is more about hypermedia and self describing messages. The point I was trying to make is that the format should not matter...If you are truly going restful, then you should not worry about consuming any sort of contract as that is owned by the server in true REST....it is a hard concept for many to understand and is the cause of much confusion...try to avoid REST just becoming RPC as REST

Comment: @youwhut You could also look at the new WebAPI, but RestSharp is pretty cool too  :) Focus on POCOs is the key