# .Net MVC Consuming Web Service

Tags: .net, web-services, model-view-controller

I can not realize the how to consume a web service from other computer or any website (if exist).

If you can give any link or information about it, I will be satisfied.

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer varies based on what type of interface the service possesses. Is it REST (like Web API) or SOAP (like an old .asmx)?

If it's **REST** all you need to do is call it via **WebRequest** and read the response:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/how-to-request-data-using-the-webrequest-class

[Consuming REST Web Service in .NET MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970542/consuming-rest-web-service-in-net-mvc-3)

If it's **SOAP** you should create a service reference and use the generated proxy class.
In Visual Studio you would go to Project -> Add Service Reference (or to the Solution Explorer tab -> Right click References -> Add Service Reference), add the url of your web service, hit GO, then if everything is all right hit Ok.
You'll see it creates a class which contains the methods in your service. Just call them like you would call any method on an object.
https://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Google might be your best friend in this case. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your explaining